# Name this ultra-bold geometric display font with triangular letter shapes (W and F)

Tags: font-identification

Can anybody tell what is the name of this font?

[image: Sample image]

I checked in [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) but it didn't show any results.

Comment: Seems like handmade letters. Could you post the link, where you found it?

Comment: sorry afterlame i have no link

Comment: Do you only have a W and F? Any other letters?

Comment: You can also ask at http://typophile.com/typeid . Normally you get answers pretty quickly. Don't forget to also post the answer here if you get it answered in the typophile forum!

Comment: thanx leguim . i will surely do that

Comment: andrew i have only those letters

Answer (score 6):

The closest match I could find so far is [P22 Constructivist Line](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/p22/constructivist/line/), which has an almost identical W, although the F is different:

[image: P22 Constructivist Line]

---

A few other Art Deco stencil fonts with a similar W that I found are:

[Ritz Stencil JNL](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/jnlevine/ritz-stencil/regular/):

[image: Ritz Stencil JNL]

[FP Palina](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontpartners/fp-palina/fp-palina/):

[image: FP Palina]

[Waddem Choo NF](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/nicksfonts/waddem-choo-nf/regular/):

[image: Waddem Choo NF]

Perhaps the best known typeface in this style is [Futura Black](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/futura-black/), whose W is similar, but lacks the sharp bottom corners:

[image: Futura Black]

I haven't managed to find anything with that triangular F yet, though.

Comment: The W is spot on but the F is completely different, weird.

Comment: The F in the question was previously used by [F-Prot](http://www.f-prot.com/) as their logo. I reckon the font is drawn, especially if the only letters are W and F.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: If you mean [this logo](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:F-Secure_logo.svg) (which was, apparently, actually used by F-Secure for several years after the two product lines split), I actually had the exact same initial reaction, but on closer inspection they're really not that similar -- except, that is, for the obvious matter of being a letter F drawn in the shape of a triangle.

Comment: Nice find! That's some funky type :D

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to identify a typeface several months ago and although WhatTheFont didn't automatically identify it, the [WhatTheFont Forum](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/) quickly [found the answer for me](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/case/547115/), so definitely try their forum as well.

Answer (score 1):

that type of font is considered a "[techno font](http://www.fonts2u.com/references/techno-fonts.html)".  try searching a few font sites that offer techno fonts and some allow you to preview the font so enter "W" and "F"