# What's the name of the font used in Ambersoft Labs?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

What is the name of this font? I have checked in many sites but could not get a proper answer. In the given picture, the letter T looks modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the font seems to match this font called "[Absolut Pro](http://www.dafont.com/absolut-pro.font?fpp=50&text=ambersoftlabs)" from Dafont.com.

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: no problem glad I could help.  I love fonts but they are my biggest enemy, too.

Comment: matt i need i more favor. i have asked one question in this website regarding fonts but couldn't get the correct answer  could mind answering that one also .the question topic is "can anybody tell me what is the name of this font?" i had asked it 15 days ago.

Comment: @Sumann Always better to give [a link](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17141/can-anybody-tell-me-what-is-the-name-of-this-font) rather than the title, particularly with such a generic title! How to include a link is given in the comment help (link on the right of the comment box).

Answer (score 0):

It looks similar to [Ubuntu web font](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Ubuntu#charset) in bold

[image]